# .Doc file is not creating properly in asp.net coming with html tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, novacode-docx

- .doc is not creating properly . creating with complete html tags
  instead of words

like below data in ms word document

```
<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_design" style="width:600px">
        <table id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rpt" border="0" width="600">
```

how to convert html tags to plain content ?

aspx.cs

```
 protected void btnMail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Response.Clear();
     try
     {
         System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
         System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
         design.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
         string strBuilder = stringWrite.ToString();
         string strPath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\Temp\\WeeklyReport of " + Projname + ".doc";


         if (File.Exists(strPath))
         {
             var counter = 1;
             strPath = strPath.Replace(".doc", " (" + counter + ").doc");
             while (File.Exists(strPath))
             {
                 strPath = strPath.Replace("(" + counter + ").doc", "(" + (counter + 1) + ").doc");
                 counter++;
             }
         }
         var doc = DocX.Create(strPath,DocumentTypes.Document);
         doc.InsertParagraph(strBuilder);
         doc.Save();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Add `runat="server"` to `div` and then using the `id of div` at serverside access the `InnerText`. You will get plain text inside the div.

Comment: <div id="design" runat="server" style="width:600px"> i already applied that @VinodKumar

Comment: OK. Then check my answer below, this should help if I understand you correctly. If not please let me know.

Comment: after which line i have to write it .which u send the code of c# @VinodKumar

Comment: Being it is a server component you can access `design.InnerText` anywhere in your code behind. To be specific `string strBuilder = design.InnerText;`. And you should not need stuff before that, what `StringWriter` and `HtmlTextWriter`.

Comment: giving error while using - string strBuilder = design.InnerText;

base {System.SystemException} = {"Cannot get inner content of design because the contents are not literal."} @VinodKumar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78379/discussion-between-coder-and-vinod-kumar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is all the text inside the div you want, then you could do this.

ASP.NET

```
<div runat="server" id="design" style="width:600px">
 SOME TEXT <span> text </span>
</div>
```

C#:

```
string allTextInsideDiv = design.InnerText; //You should get "SOME TEXT text"
```

**Edited:**
In further to our discussion you could not get InnerText as you have some ASP.NET server controls inside the div. So the solution would be to get the HTML code and using an XmlDocument or HtmlDocument object, load the content into it. Then extract the InnerText out.

Sample code:

```
System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter(); 
System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite); 
div_myDiv.RenderControl(htmlWrite); 
string myText = stringWrite.ToString().Replace("&", "&amp;");
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument(); 
xDoc.LoadXml(myText); 
string rawText = xDoc.InnerText;
```